# Set up Firebase email verification without Apple Developer Account

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm currently working on an IOS app and I'm using Firebase to deal with all the logging in and authentication.

I would like to set up email verification but every tutorial online says that my Dynamic Link needs to be registered in Xcode as an "Associated Domain". It doesn't seem I can do that without a developer account which I don't want to buy just yet

Is there any way that I can set up email verification without paying for a developer account?

Thank you,

Ethan

Comment: What is the Firebase email verification?  Are you talking about one of the sign-in providers?

Comment: Yes, its under email. The option is called "Email link (passwordless sign-in)" and it sends a verification email to the user before they can use their account

Comment: I see.  I have never used that option.  Why don't you test it without the email link, then?

Comment: I currently have it set up without but I would like to add in the email verification

Answer (score 1):

You *can* use Firebase Authentication's email verification without setting up an associated domain The only difference is that in that case you can't automatically re-open the app when the user clicks the link, as that requires the domain association. So the user will have to (re) open the app themselves, but aside from that email verification itself will work fine.